# Component not assignable after implementing class

Tags: typescript, angular

Can anyone tell me why TypeScript says `'typeof MyComponent' is not assignable to type 'Renderer'. Property 'input' is missing in type 'typeof MyComponent'`
when MyComponent implements Rendered?

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

interface Renderer {
    input: string;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'some-other-selector',
    template: 'hello-mum'
})
class MyComponent implements Renderer {
    @Input() input: string;
}


@Component({
    selector: 'dynamic-list-app',
    template: 'hello-world'
})
export class DynamicListAppComponent {
    renderer: Renderer;
    constructor() {
        this.renderer = MyComponent;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can **extend** a class, *implement* an interface...

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/tutorial.html

Comment: So that's what I thought but I get the same issue when it's an interface. I've updated the example above.I'm using Angular 2 RC.2 and TS 1.8

Answer (score 2):

The `renderer` field requires instance of type `Renderer`, but you are assigning class `MyComponent`. `typeof MyComponent` is similar to java `Class<MyComponent>` which is obviously not instance of `Renderer`.

It should be `this.renderer = new MyComponent();`

Comment: Renderer has to to a component class and not an instance as I'm using it as a Dynamic component. I've updated the code above to use an interface but i still have the same issue.